# Adding data in the migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My data seems to be not loading when I do a migration with ruby on rails.

Can anyone see the problem?

```
class CreateAds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :ads do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.string :image
      t.integer :price
      t.string :featured
      t.string :state
      t.string :zipcode
      t.boolean :is_public
      t.boolean :is_activated
      t.timestamp :expires_at
      t.float :longitude
      t.float :latitude

      t.timestamps
    end
    Ad.create  :title => "notice"
  end
```

model source:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categories
    belongs_to :user
end
```

After, I do `rake db:migrate`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any validations setup for the model that it could be failing during the create?

Comment: Any validations or such on the model?

Comment: What does the model's source look like? What happens if you `Ad.reset_column_information` before `Ad.create`?

Comment: model source: class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :categories
 belongs_to :user
end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this right before Ad.create:

```
Ad.reset_column_information
```

Comment: I still have problems, it worked the first time, now, not so much, it might have something to do with the fact that I deleted rows in the database? anyway, seeds.rb works well, I will use that, thanks